# Simple jQuery to change background images in the form of a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the <`div id="highlighted">` style there is this background image

```
background: url(image.jpg) top center no-repeat transparent;
```

What I want to do is to include a list of background images to be changed like a simple jquery slideshow with fadeout or something.

How can I do this with simple jQuery coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

really easy to use

```
 $.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

Comment: thank you for this. but how do i bind it in to that div?

Comment: ```$('.foo').backstretch([
  'path/to/image.jpg',
  'path/to/image2.jpg',
  'path/to/image3.jpg'
]);``` Something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ["image.jpg",Chrysanthemum.jpg", "Desert.jpg", "Hydrangeas.jpg", "Jellyfish.jpg", "Koala.jpg", "Lighthouse.jpg", "Penguins.jpg", "Tulips.jpg"];
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#highlighted").css("background-image", "url(images/" + images[i] + ")");
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $("#highlighted").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/" + images[i] +  ")");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```